# How can i create user with multiple Client roles in a single API

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I want to create a user and assign a client role with it **in a single** API in Keycloak I have attached the details.

I have this API

`http://testkeycloak.com:8085/auth/admin/realms/engineer/users`

```
{   
    "enabled":true,
    "username":"joshbiden",
    "email":"email@gmail.com",
    "firstName":"Josh",
    "lastName":"biden",
    "attributes": 
    {
        "Mobile Number":"3333332332"
    },
    "clientRoles": 
    {
        "name": "DEVELOPER"
    },
    "credentials":
    [
    {
        "type":"password",
        "value":"rollback",
        "temporary":false
    }
    ]
}
```

CLIENT ROLE - DETAILS

```
    {
        "id": "32e432da-d0c0-45f8-a67d-f3146b7a24b4",
        "name": "DEVELOPER",
        "composite": false,
        "clientRole": true,
        "containerId": "343434-7631-4187-ac76-ad78de119b90"
    }
```

How can I assign two clients' roles to the USER, I have tried to add users but facing an unknown error. Let me know any solution for the same

Answer (score 11):

> I want to create a user and assign a client role with it in a single
> API in Keycloak I have attached the details.

Unfortunately, it is impossible to do that with a single API call, even though the [Keycloak Admin rest API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html) documentation infers otherwise. This can be confirmed by looking at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/13390). Quoting the [reply from that thread](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/13390#issuecomment-1260911941) (from the Keycloak Project Leader [Stian Thorgersen](https://github.com/stianst)):

So, unfortunately, the answer from [@Devendra Mahajan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72187690/1366871) is simply not correct.

---

The solution is to perform two calls, namely:

1. one to create the user
2. another to assign the roles

First create the user using the endpoint `POST /{realm}/users` and with the following data (without the role):

```
{
  "username": "joshbiden",
  "enabled": true,
  "firstName": "Josh",
  "lastName": "biden",
  "email": "email@gmail.com",
  "attributes": {
    "Mobile Number": [
      "3333332332"
    ]
  },
  "credentials": [{
    "type":"password",
    "value":"rollback",
    "temporary":false
  }]
}
```

Second, you assign the role using the endpoint :

`POST /{realm}/users/{id}/role-mappings/clients/{id of client}`

with the data:

```
[{
  "id": "32e432da-d0c0-45f8-a67d-f3146b7a24b4",
  "name": "DEVELOPER",
  "composite": false,
  "clientRole": true,
  "containerId": "343434-7631-4187-ac76-ad78de119b90"
}]
```

---

**Step-by-Step**

**Warning:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

To use [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html) you need an access token from a user with the proper permissions. I will be using the `admin` user from the `master` realm:

```bash
curl "https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token" \
    -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
    -d "username=$ADMIN_NAME" \
    -d "password=$ADMIN_PASSWORD" \
    -d "grant_type=password"
```

You will get a JSON with the admin's token. Extract the value of property `access_token` from that response. Let us save it in the variable `$ACCESS_TOKEN` for later reference.

To [create the user](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html#_createuser) in your realm `$REALM_NAME`:

```bash
curl -X POST "https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}/users"
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN" \
     -d "${USER_JSON_DATA}"
```

For those that need you can also have a look at my scripts to automatize the user creation on GitHub, namely [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72187690/1366871) or [this](https://github.com/dreamcrash/Keycloak/blob/main/scripts/createUser).

To assign the client role to the user you need the know beforehand the following fields:

1. id of the user
2. id of the client
3. client role representation

To [get the user id](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html#_getusers) from your realm `$REALM_NAME`:

```bash
curl -X GET "https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}/users/?username=${USERNAME}" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

From the response extract the user `id` for example as follows

```
jq -r ".[] | select(.username==\"$USERNAME\")" | jq -r id
```

and save it in the variable `${USER_ID}`.

To get the client `id` call the endpoint [get clients](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.3/rest-api/index.html#_getclients) with the parameter `clientID`:

```
curl -X GET "${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}/clients?clientId=${CLIENT_ID}" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}"
```

Extract id from the response (*e.g.,*  jq -r .[0].id) and save it in variable `${ID_OF_CLIENT}`.

With the previous `id` you can get the client role as follows:

```
curl -X GET "http://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}/clients/${ID_OF_CLIENT}/roles/${ROLE_NAME}" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}"
```

Save the json response in `${CLIENT_ROLE}`, and assign the role to the user as follows:

```
curl  -X POST "http://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}/users/${USER_ID}/role-mappings/clients/${ID_OF_CLIENT}" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
        -d "${CLIENT_ROLE}"
```

**I have created scripts** for the aforementioned steps that can be accessed [here](https://github.com/dreamcrash/StackOverflow-/blob/main/Keycloak/RestAdminAPI/Roles) and executed using the script [getClientRoleByName.sh](https://github.com/dreamcrash/StackOverflow-/blob/main/Keycloak/RestAdminAPI/Roles/getClientRoleByName.sh).

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
{
  "enabled": true,
  "username": "joshbiden",
  "email": "email@gmail.com",
  "firstName": "Josh",
  "lastName": "biden",
  "attributes": {
    "Mobile Number": "3333332332"
  },
  "clientRoles": {
    "<name-of-the-client-in-realm>": ["DEVELOPER"]
  },
  "credentials": [
    {
      "type": "password",
      "value": "rollback",
      "temporary": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi there, unfortunately this answer does not work

Comment: Yes, this is not working for me as well

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using the partial import API

```
POST /{realm}/partialImport
```

With this API you can also import multiple users in one call.
This is not a solution for update though.

Body sample:

```
{
"users": [
    {
        "username": "user1",
        "enabled": true,
        "totp": false,
        "emailVerified": true,
        "firstName": "First name",
        "lastName": "Last name",
        "disableableCredentialTypes": [],
        "requiredActions": [],
        "notBefore": 0,
        "access": {
            "manageGroupMembership": true,
            "view": true,
            "mapRoles": true,
            "impersonate": true,
            "manage": true
        },
        "groups": [
            
        ],
        "realmRoles": [
            
        ]
    },
    {
        "username": "user2",
        "enabled": true,
        "totp": false,
        "emailVerified": true,
        "firstName": "User 2",
        "lastName": "Last name",
        "disableableCredentialTypes": [],
        "requiredActions": [],
        "notBefore": 0,
        "access": {
            "manageGroupMembership": true,
            "view": true,
            "mapRoles": true,
            "impersonate": true,
            "manage": true
        },
        "groups": [

        ],
        "realmRoles": [
            "some realm role"
        ],
        "clientRoles": {
            "some client": [
                "some client role"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is basically extra information on top of [dreamcrash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71318973/785194), which was too long for a comment.

To add multiple roles, supply an array as follows:

```
curl \
   "http://$host/admin/realms/$realm/users/$user_uuid/role-mappings/clients/$client_uuid" \
   -H "Authorization: bearer $token"   \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -d "[{\"id\":\"uuid-for-RoleA\",\"name\":\"RoleA\"},{\"id\":\"uuid-for-RoleB\",\"name\":\"RoleB\"},{etc}]"
```

This is for `bash`, so I've added extra backslashes as required for the JSON quotes.

The roles must be supplied as an array of [RoleRepresentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/21.0.1/rest-api/index.html#_rolerepresentation) objects. The only two fields which appear to be mandatory are `id` and `name` (bizarrely, you need both the `id` and `name`; tested on Keycloak 23.0.1). You can alternatively supply the whole `RoleRepresentation` as shown in the answer above. So, in short, you need to find lots of UUIDs before starting: the user, the client, and one for each role you want.

Note also that this does *not* set the client roles: it simply *adds* client roles. You must also remove any client roles you don't want, using `DELETE` rather than `POST`. So, the whole thing's a bit of a mess.

The `kcadm.sh` alternative is much simpler, because you don't need to find any UUIDs, but you still have to delete the roles you don't want.